# Can I use graphite/statsd for data with specific date attached to it?

Tags: graphite, statsd

I'm trying to create a graph for sales data.

Some sales data is at the moment collected in a database we don't own.

We can only access the data through web admin to the database.

They won't be providing us any api to import the data though programming.

We can download data in cvs format through the web admin and that's as convenient as we can get.

I want to plot this data, and wonder if I could use graphite/statsd for this.
I'm fairly new to graphite and examples I've seen so far deals with data that is happening in real time. (without the time tag which describes when events happened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Take a look on docs - [feeding graphite](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/feeding-carbon.html). The simplest solution is to send over tcp with line protocol - just send `<metric_path> <value> <timestamp>` e.g.

```
echo "test.bash.stats 42 `date +%s`" | nc graphite.example.com 2003
#     metric.to.update value timestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

As @kwarunek says in the other answer, yes you can send the data to Graphite and have it plotted using its render utilities or Grafana.

However I believe that is an overkill if you already have a CSV file with the data. I suggest you simply use `pandas` and `matplotlib` to analyze and plot the data.

Comment: yeah, I just thought it might be beneficial to have one system to collect data (graphite) than to have multiple systems.

Comment: @eugene you can always go the other way around. Export the data you collect in Graphite to CSV and then plot analyze and plot all the data in Excel / pandas + matplotlib.